# How do I show TextView's in LinearLayout that layed on other Layout?

Tags: java, android, layout, show

Good day.

I have three layouts: first is the root, second and third lie in first. I try add TextView object in third layout and objects had been added in third layout (I saw it in debage mode) but this objects didn't showed on screen.

May be someone know where is the problem?

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addJokeButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
        />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/newJokeEditText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    </LinearLayout>    

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

    protected void initLayout() {
    setContentView(R.layout.advanced);

    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.advanced, null);
    m_vwJokeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newJokeEditText);
    m_vwJokeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addJokeButton);
    m_vwJokeLayout = (LinearLayout) linearLayout.getChildAt(1);
}

    protected void addJoke(Joke joke) {
    m_arrJokeList.add(joke);

    LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    setColor(textView);
    textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    textView.setText(joke.getJoke());

    m_vwJokeLayout.addView(textView);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this sample example

```
  package com.example.helloandroid;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.widget.LinearLayout;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

  public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
TextView textview;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LinearLayout ll= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01); 


      LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

      LinearLayout childLayout= new LinearLayout(this);
      childLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  
      TextView text = new TextView(this);
      text.setText("High");
      childLayout.addView(text);
      ll.addView(childLayout, lp);

}
```

}`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout 
 android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:orientation="vertical"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <TextView 
  android:id="@+id/textview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:text="@string/hello"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

or make use of following link

[Creating Linear Layout with TextViews using a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576848/creating-linear-layout-with-textviews-using-a-for-loop/4577351#4577351)

Comment: Thanks HellBoy. You help me, I am very grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access LayoutParams like this

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

and also you are declaring  linearLayout as local variable on fallowing line use it as class variable. so that it is accessible out side method.

```
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.advanced, null);
```

Comment: Big thanks for your answer, HellBoy, but I can't accept this way. What if I want add more views - 10, 100, 1000? I realy didn't know how much jokes will be added. You have idea how can do it?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I have layout as class variable (m_vwJokeLayout) but it's contain only third layout (with jokes) because I didn't use other layouts. Althought, I tried to do as you said - it didn't work. How often do you use dynamicly add something on the layout? I mean maybe you would show your way how do it?