# Creating Linear Layout with TextViews using a for loop

Tags: java, android, textview, android-linearlayout

I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically create an additional linear layout with a textview within a predefined liner layout. THis is my code so you get the gist of what I am asking:

```
LinearLayout MainLL= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayoutId); 

  for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
   LinearLayout childLL= new LinearLayout(this);
   childLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  
   childLL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));  
   childLL.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

 TextView text = new TextView(this);
   text.setText("The Value of i is :"i);
   text.setTextSize(12);  
   text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
   text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
childLL.addView(text);
MainLL.addView(childLL);
}
```

My problem is that I am only getting "The Value of i is :0" as the output, i.e. the first instance.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to wrap the TextView inside another LinearLayout, you can do just:

```
LinearLayout MainLL= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayoutId); 
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
 TextView text = new TextView(this);
   text.setText("The Value of i is :"+i); // <-- does it really compile without the + sign?
   text.setTextSize(12);  
   text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
   text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
MainLL.addView(text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks all, you have pointed me in the right direction but I figured out my flaw. I forgot to have a setContent view. Adding the following to the end solved the problem: this.setContentView(MainLL);

Answer (score 0):

Everything you are doing is correct just make it

```
childLL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

because your parent layout is filled by 1st view because  of that you can not see other view.

and yes

```
 text.setText("The Value of i is :"+i); //add + sign
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you greatly need to wrap another LinearLayout before wrapping the TextView.
Please try this code:

```
childLL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```

This will ensure the wrapped LinearLayout has the same weight, so all the views will be displayed on the screen.